# Resizing WPF listview columns with width proportional to text width

Tags: wpf, listview, resize

I have a WPF ListView table that on default sizes the column headers to the width of each header's text.  This does not fill the entire table evenly; I have a mass of squeezed columns on the left and a vacant space on the right.

I would like to be able to resize the columns to a width proportional to the longest item in the column's text, of the header or the rows.  How would I do this?

What I am currently doing is initially resizing the headers to widths proportional to the headers' text, using the following code (where SearchResultsTable is the ListView):

```cs
private void Resize()
{
    var width = SearchResultsTable.ActualWidth;
    var gridView = SearchResultsTable.View as GridView;
    var columns = new GridViewColumnCollection();
    if (gridView != null)
    {
        columns = gridView.Columns;
    }
    var initialColumnWidths = columns.Sum(column => column.ActualWidth);
    var scale = width / initialColumnWidths;
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        column.Width = column.ActualWidth * scale;
    }
}
```

However, this only resizes based on the header text width; I don't know how to get the maximum width of the header and rows.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am doing.  Hope this helps.  You can get or set the width of the GridView columns in the ListView, and I am using the width of the ListView control itself to increase/decrease the relative width of each ListView column to proportionally fill the space - and then extending the last column.

What you could do is modify my code to distribute the difference between the total widths of the columns and the width of the ListView proportionally across the set of columns in the conditional "if (total_width < e.NewSize.Width" where I am just adding that difference to the last column width.

```
LV_FileList.SizeChanged += this.onLV_FileList_SizeChanged;
```

...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Proportionally resize listview columns when listview size changes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void onLV_FileList_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender is ListView) && 
            (e.PreviousSize.Width > 0))
        {
            double total_width = 0;
            GridViewColumnCollection gvcc = ((GridView)(sender as ListView).View).Columns;
            foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gvcc)
            {
                gvc.Width = (gvc.Width / e.PreviousSize.Width) * e.NewSize.Width;
                total_width += gvc.Width;
            }

            //Increase width of last column to fit width of listview if integer division made the total width to small
            if (total_width < e.NewSize.Width)
            {
                gvcc[gvcc.Count - 1].Width += (e.NewSize.Width - total_width);
            }

            //Render changes to ListView before checking for horizontal scrollbar
            this.AllowUIToUpdate();

            //Decrease width of last column to eliminate scrollbar if it is displayed now
            ScrollViewer svFileList = this.FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(LV_FileList);
            while ((svFileList.ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility != Visibility.Collapsed) &&  (gvcc[gvcc.Count - 1].Width > 1))
            {
                gvcc[gvcc.Count - 1].Width--;
                this.AllowUIToUpdate();
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Threaded invocation to handle updating UI in resize loop
    /// </summary>
    private void AllowUIToUpdate()
    {
        DispatcherFrame dFrame = new DispatcherFrame();

        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(object parameter)
        {
            dFrame.Continue = false;
            return null;

        }), null);

        Dispatcher.PushFrame(dFrame);
    }
```